# Simper way to structure json response?

Tags: c#, json

In golang there is a `gin` framework can custom json structure:

```
authorized.GET("/secrets", func(c *gin.Context) {
    // get user, it was set by the BasicAuth middleware
    user := c.MustGet(gin.AuthUserKey).(string)
    if secret, ok := secrets[user]; ok {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"user": user, "secret": secret})
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"user": user, "secret": "NO SECRET"})
    }
})
```

If the user is ok, return:

```
{
  "user: "user",
  "secret: "secret"
}
```

otherwise it return:

```
{
  "user: "user",
  "secret: "NO SECRET"
}
```

it is really convenient for custom json response, But in my experience with C#, I have to create a another Class to structure the json response.

Is there have same way as golang in C# to easily structure json response?

Comment: You can return an anonymous type and it's even less syntax. In ASP.NET you might return `Ok(new { user = "user", secret = "secret})`.

Comment: thanks for you reply, Is there some Microsoft docs provide?

Comment: [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

Answer (score -1):

c.JSON also support go struct parameter

```golang
type Response struct {
  User string  `json:"user"`
  Secret string `json:"secret"`
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, Response{User:"your name", Secret:"secret"})
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am question about C#